# Strange getline behavior in c++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I have the following file:

```
BB
7.501106 5.324115
7.997006 8.287983
11.314904 11.768281
...
```

And i am 100% sure that the file is ok, i have even shown newlines in vim with `:set list` :

```
BB$
7.501106 5.324115$
7.997006 8.287983$
11.314904 11.768281$
...
```

But when i open and read in the first line something wierd happens. I have the following code:

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
std::string line;
if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "parseConfig: Error opening config file: " << filename << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

getline(file, line);
std::cout << "line is: <" << line << ">" << std::endl;
if (line.compare("BB")) {
    std::cerr << "parseConfig: Error in config file, first line is not BB" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Now i know the file is being opened correctly because we get all the way to the final error.

The print out is as following:

```
>ine is: <BB    //What!!!??  Why did this happen?
parseConfig: Error in config file, first line is not BB
```

Which strikes me as odd, its as if there is a carriage return in the text file. But i am so sure that there is not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the file is in DOS mode. Check if vim displays `[dos]` at the bottom, or check `file yourfile.txt`.

Another way to check is by piping the file or the output of your program through `cat -A` (or `cat -v` if your cat doesn't have `-A`). Carriage returns will show up as `^M`.

To convert to UNIX format, do `:set ff=unix` in vim and then save the file. Or use the `dos2unix` command-line tool if you have it.